# Replace "&#x2" with "0x02" in the entire file using sed

Tags: sed

I need to replace all the occurrences of `&#x2` with `0x02` using `sed`. Will the following work or I'll have to use `\`?

```
sed -i -E "s/<&#x2>/<0x02>/g" $output_file
```

If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: What Unix are you on? The `-i` option to `sed` works very differently on various systems.  You also include `<` and `>` in your pattern and replacement text, could you explain why (these weren't in the question before then)?  The pattern is a string, not a regular expression, so the `-E` option seems not needed (it enables _extended_ regular expressions, of which you use none).  Also, are you wanting to run this on some file whose name is in the variable `output_file`, or shoud that be the output file name, as opposed to the input file name (which isn't mentioned)?

Comment: Basically I need to replace all the occurrences of &#x2 with 0x02. I am unable to figure out if the pattern  is a string simply or is considered as special characters since it starting with &?
output_file is a variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no special characters in the string `&#x2` that needs to be escaped for the string to be interpreted literally in the pattern part of  a `s///` command in `sed`.

There are furthermore no special characters in the replacement string `0x02` that needs to be treated specially (`&` would have been special in the replacement, as would `\1`, `\2` etc. and `\n`, `\t` etc. if you're using GNU `sed`).

This means you should be able to just do

```
sed 's/&#x2/0x02/g' inputfile >outputfile
```

The only thing that may need to be treated especially is to avoid replacing `&#x2` when it occurs in substrings such as `&#x23`.  Since I don't see any example document in the question I can't say exactly if this would be an issue and how to best protect against it.

In general, *don't* use the `-i` option with `sed` until you have a `sed` editing expression or script that you know works, to avoid accidentally loosing data.  You also don't need `-E` here as we're not dealing with extended regular expressions at all.

If you are running the `sed` command on a file whose name is kept in a variable, remember to double quote the expansion of that variable (see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)).

Comment: Very well explained . Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @user13583928 Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).